# How to get someones account age like carl bot (e.g. 9 months ago, not the date it was) discord.py

Tags: discord.py

My code says the exact date of when a discord account was made. How do u do it so it says how many months/days/hours it was created ago. This is what I have so far:

```
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
   await ctx.send(ctx.author.created_at)
```

Comment: you can use `datetime.timedelta()` function of  `datetime` library to calculate difference between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get todays date and subtract it from the created_at date. You'll get a timedelta obj

```py
from datetime import datetime

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    delta = now - ctx.author.created_at # Format it as you want

    await ctx.send(delta)
```